# Ant metadata api conditional argument

Tags: metadata-api, ant, migration-tool

I am updating an ant script to specify a `testLevel` argument. However we'd like to have this argument be optional.

I'm fairly new to ant and wondering if theres a way to conditional see if the argument is passed in and if not to default to `NoTestRun`

```
<target name="deploy">
   <sf:deploy username="${user}" password="${pass}" serverurl="${url}"
        maxPoll="${maxPoll}" pollWaitMillis="${pollWaitMillis}"
        deployRoot="${basedir}/src" testLevel="${testLevel}" checkOnly="${checkOnly}" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the property using [`property`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).

```
<target name="deploy">
   <property name="testLevel" value="NoTestRun" />
   <sf:deploy username="${user}" password="${pass}" serverurl="${url}"
        maxPoll="${maxPoll}" pollWaitMillis="${pollWaitMillis}"
        deployRoot="${basedir}/src" testLevel="${testLevel}" checkOnly="${heckOnly}" />
</target>
```

The trick with property is that they are *immutable*, meaning a property can be set only once. If it was set by command-line or an env task previously, the property tag will have no effect. Otherwise, it will be set and the value will be NoTestRun.

Comment: After applying this update without specifying `testLevel` in the command line, it spits out an error.



'${testLevel}' is not a permitted value for testLevel.You must specify testLevel from following options: 
1. NoTestRun
2. RunSpecifiedTests
3. RunLocalTests
4. RunAllTestsInOrg

Comment: @Programatic Check for spelling errors. It's also cAsE sEnSiTiVe, as in Java.